# How to replace a helmet slot with a player skull

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to swap the helmet slot of an armor stand from one player head to another in Minecraft 1.14.4. One head is obtained from minecraft-heads.com, and the other is a real player's head.

When I run this command:

```
replaceitem entity @e[name=Intro] armor.head minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Closed\"}"},SkullOwner:{Id:"2fd224ce-af3d-42f9-abbe-707e29cecc45",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYzk1ZWFhYzIxODQ4NzU1ZTEwZDAyNTllMDNmYTVhMmI5Y2NjNTUwOWQzMDJjNmQxODllYmZiMDM5MjVjNTc2In19fQ=="}]}}}
```

The correct skull is replaced on to the armor stand. However, whenever I run this command:

```
replaceitem entity @e[name=Intro] armor.head minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Open\"}"},SkullOwner:{Id:"Skraby_"}}
```

The skull that gets placed on the armor stand is just a regular steve head. This is my current username, and I can obtain the correct skull when using /give, so my question is, why doesn't this work? I can't find any other ways this would be run. Everywhere I look says that this should be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Id` tag is for the UUID of the player:

> **Id:** UUID of owner. Optional. Used to update the other tags when the chunk loads or the holder logs in, in case the owner's name has changed.
> <sub>from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head#Item_data)</sub>

What you want is `Name`:

> **Name:** Username of owner. If missing or empty, the head appears as a Steve head. Otherwise, used to store or retrieve the downloaded skin in the cache. Need not be a valid player name, but must not be all spaces.
> <sub>also from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head#Item_data)</sub>

So the command would be:

```
replaceitem entity @e[name=Intro] armor.head minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Open\"}"},SkullOwner:{Name:"Skraby_"}}
```

Comment: More information on why players heads are strange: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-146631